# Changing user attribute format in dynamic translation using FME?

Tags: fme-form

I'm a newbie in FME, and I've been asked to do a massive translation from MapInfo TAB to ESRI File Geodatabase. There are a lot of files so I don't know the schema.

The merge feature reader and dynamic writer look to work well. But for some features, there is an attribute that the writer cannot write, normally logic or date attribute.

I'm trying to change those attributes format to text.

Is there anyway to do this in FME?

Comment: What version of FME are you using?  What File Geodatabase writer are you using?  API or the ArcObjects one?  I just experimented with this and created a mapinfo table with a Logical field, a Date Field, a Time Field and a DateTime field.  FME dynamically converted the Logical to text and the Date, Time, and DateTime fields to Date types in my resulting feature class.  Could you post the error your getting?

Comment: FME 2014, with filegdb API. This is the line in the log "WARN  |FileGDB Writer: The `OSMM' attribute could not be written. The containing feature has been dropped". OSMM attribute  is type 'Logic'. The feature is written in the filegdb but empty.

Comment: I think it's probable that the logic values are Y/N or True/False rather than 1/0 and that FME is trying to map them to a numeric value. Hence the information is dropped. If you can use the ArcObjects Writer instead of the API one, then it should be OK. Otherwise I suggest contacting the support team (http://safe.com/support) and explaining to them. Give them the reference number PR#40212 and they might be able to give a better solution or workaround for you.